# scp hangs in scipt sometimes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, networking

I need some help to try and figure out a problem we are experiencing.  We had the following bash shell script running in devices on two separate networks (network1 and network2).  Both networks go to the same destination server.

```
while 
do
    # do something ...
    scp *.zip "$username@$server_ip:$destination_directory"
    # do something ...
    sleep 30
done
```

The script worked fine until a recent change to network2 where the scp command in the script above sometimes hangs for hours before resetting.  The same script is still working fine on netowrk1 which did not change.  We are not able identify what the issue is with network2, everything seem to work except scp.  The hang does not happened on every try but when it does hang it hangs for hours.

So I changed the scp command as follow and it now resets within minutes and the data delay is bearable but not desirable.

```
scp -o BatchMode=yes -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -o \
        ConnectTimeout=60 *.zip "$username@$server_ip:$destination_directory"
```

I also tried sftp as follows;

```
sftp -o ConnectTimeout=60 -b "batchfiles.txt" "$username@$server_ip"
```

The ConnectTimeout does not seem to work well in sftp because it still hangs for hours sometimes.  So I am back to using scp.

I even included the -o IdentityFile=path_to_key/id_rsa option in both scp and sftp thinking it maybe an authentication issue.  That did not work either.

What is really strange is that it always works when I issue the same commands from a terminal.  The shell script run as a background task.  I am running Linux 3.8.0-26-generic #38-Ubuntu and OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4.  I don’t think is a local script permissions issue because; 1) it worked before network2 changed, 2) It works some of the time.

I did a network packet capture.  I can see that each time when the scp command hangs it is accompanied by [TCP Retransmission] and [RST, ACK] within seconds from the start of a scp conversation.

I am very confused as to if the issue is networks or script related.  Base on the sequence of events I am thinking is likely due to the recent change in network2.  But why the same command works from a terminal every time I tried?

Can someone kindly tell me what my issue is or tell me how to go about troubleshoot it?

Thank you for reading and helping.

Comment: you've done a lot of analysis. It seems most likely this is a result of changes made to network2. Do you know what those changes were? What did your network people say? OR use `scp -vvv . ...` and hope you get a hint there. Good luck.

Comment: Do the failures occur at the same time of day? Can you run the script manually at that time of day? Where does it hang exactly? Add `-vvv` to the `scp` command and get a packet capture and see what `scp` thinks is happening when it hangs.

Comment: It happens randomly. I ran scp with -vvv from a terminal five times and keep getting the same output.